# how do I open pdf file using urlconnection cache

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I have a problem. I don't understand how you can implement pdf viewing quickly. I use `urlconnection` to open pdf but it takes a very long time to load. I want to make caching so that when I re-view the pdf, there would be no download. Please tell me how this can be done?I would be very grateful if someone could tell me and show me how to do this.

My code:

```
        myPDFListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                setContentView(R.layout.viewfile_activity);
                if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)){
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                }
                else
                {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                }
                pdfView=findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
                uploadPDF uploadPDF = uploadPDFS.get(position);
                new RetrievePDFStream().execute(uploadPDF.url);
            }
        });

    }
    class RetrievePDFStream extends AsyncTask<String,Void,InputStream> {
        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;


            try {

                URL urlx = new URL(strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlx.openConnection();
                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {

                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                }
                CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
                CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
            return inputStream;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {

            pdfView.fromStream(inputStream)
                    .enableSwipe(true)
                    .load();


        }

    }
    private void viewAllFiles() {
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    uploadPDF uploadPDF = postSnapshot.getValue(com.tokha.diplom.uploadPDF.class);
                    uploadPDFS.add(uploadPDF);
                }
                String[] uploads = new String[uploadPDFS.size()];
                for(int i = 0;i<uploads.length;i++){
                    uploads[i] = uploadPDFS.get(i).getName();
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, uploads){
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        TextView myText = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                        myText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.autorization));
                        return view;
                    }
                };
                myPDFListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

  }
```

Comment: If you want disk caching with HTTPS requests, please consider using [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/), as [it offers caching as part of its standard features](https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/caching/).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i am redaction my code with problem